# Xampp localhost configuration

Tags: dns, xampp, localhost

I was wondering if it's possible to make sure that xampp runs some local dev domains when I enter them in my browser - making sure it accesses the files in my /htcods/webdev.nl.geek.local for example.

Can I configure it to show this (just an example) and load my website stored in htdocs? For example: http://www.testwebsite.com.paul.local

Thanks!

Comment: Sure you can. You just have to define the desired hosts inside your http server and take care that the domain names are resolved to that http servers ip address locally.

Comment: My HTTP server? Within Xampp or in any configuration file?

Comment: The apache http server is part of the xampp distribution (I never understood why people use xyzampp instead of simply installing the packages themselves and use them, but that is another story...). Inside the apache http server you can define "virtual hosts". That is what you have to do. It is well documented. I am sure you will figure that out and there are about 65926594649 examples for that alone here on StackOverflow: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/